# JQuery function only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this is an elementary question but I can't get the script below to function more than once. I have trien using .live() and .on() without success either. It works fine once but then ceases to work.

```
$('.chk_av').click(function(){
    var new_user=$('.new_uname').val();
    if(new_user=="")
    {
        return;
    }
    var data="new_user="+new_user+"&agent_id="+agent_id+"&key=1";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"admin_includes/change_pwrd.php",
        data:data,
        success:function(html){
            if(html==1)
            {
                $('.js_alert3').text("Username already in use.").fadeOut(5000);
                return;
            }
            if(html==2)
            {
                $('.js_alert3').text("Username Free.").fadeOut(5000);
                return;
            }
        }
    })//end ajax
});
```

Comment: Are you certain the function is firing only once? If you put a `console.log('hello')` as the first line of the function, then click the element twice, do you see the log once or twice? If twice, the function is firing each time as desired, but something in it is either returning (you do have several return statements...) or error'ing.

Comment: The `'.js_alert3'` element isn't a parent of the `'.chk_av'` element is it? Is `'.chk_av'` otherwise overwritten or recreated dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you missed fadeIn() in above code.

```
$('.chk_av').click(function(){
        var new_user=$('.new_uname').val();
        if(new_user=="")
        {
            return;
        }
        var data="new_user="+new_user+"&agent_id="+agent_id+"&key=1";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"admin_includes/change_pwrd.php",
            data:data,
            success:function(html){
                if(html==1)
                {
                    $('.js_alert3').text("Username already in use.").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
                    return;
                }
                if(html==2)
                {
                    $('.js_alert3').text("Username Free.").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
                    return;
                }
            }
        })//end ajax
    });
```

Comment: As you have pointed out, the problem is the omission of the fadeIn() element and not a problem with the function not firing. I will look for a better way of getting the desired text effect so that it does not queue. Thanks